# How to use string as a y-axis value in openpyxl's ScatterChart?

Tags: python, openpyxl

It seems that currently only integer is supported as a value in y-axis. I can't use BarChart because it didn't accept xvalues in Series.

```
    # the columns value here is int
    values = Reference(ws, (2, 2), (10, 2))
    # the columns value here is string
    values2 = Reference(ws, (2, 1), (10, 1))
    series = Series(values, xvalues=values2, title="Chart")
    chart = ScatterChart()
    chart.append(series)
    ws.add_chart(chart)
    wb.save(file_name) # exception

File "/lib/python3.4/site-packages/openpyxl/charts/graph.py", line 31, in compute_axes
    mini, maxi = self._get_extremes('xvalues')
File "/lib/python3.4/site-packages/openpyxl/charts/graph.py", line 58, in _get_extremes
    return min(series_min), max(series_max)
TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() < int()
```

Answer (score 1):

Without sample data it's hard to say much but one thing to note that a data series have both data sets and labels. A ScatterChart cannot really work with non-numerical axes.

There is an example of a BarChart with labels in the project's sample code.